# Taking a score from one activity to another in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

I've been trying to work this out but to no avail.

I have a score that is obtained in the `GameView` class using the `int hitCount` inside the `onTouchEvent` method.  This is being calculated fine.  What I need to do is pass the total score to `MainMenu` class where it says 'Total Number of Hits'.

I have this 'finish' method in the **GameActivity class:**

```
public void finish(){
    Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    super.finish();
}
```

**GameView class:**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    /* Member (state) fields   */
    private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
    private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object 
    /**
     * The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas
     */
    private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
    // For creating the game Sprite
    private Sprite sprite;
    // For recording the number of hits
    private int hitCount;
    // To track if a game is over
    private boolean gameOver;
    // To play sound
    private SoundPlayer sound;
    //int backButtonCount = 0;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
        this.setFocusable(true);
        // For intercepting events on the surface.
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        // Background image added
        mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.half_moon);
        //sound = new SoundPlayer(this);
    }

    /* Called immediately after the surface created */
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
        ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
        mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
        gameLoopThread.running = true;
        gameLoopThread.start();
    }

    // For the countdown timer
    private long startTime; // Timer to count down from
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 sec interval
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // Reference to the class
    private boolean timerRunning = false;
    private String displayTime; // To display the time on the screen

    //To initialise/reset game
    private void ResetGame() {
        /* Set paint details */
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        sprite = new Sprite(this);
        hitCount = 0;
        // Set timer
        startTime = 10; // Start at 10s to count down
        // Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime * 1000, interval);
        countDownTimer.start(); // Start the time running
        timerRunning = true;
        gameOver = false;
    }

    // Countdown Timer - private class
    private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //displayTime = "Time is up!";
            timerRunning = false;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            gameOver = true;
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        }
    }


    //This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
    public void update() {
        sprite.update();
    }

    /**
     * To draw the game to the screen
     * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
     */
    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw all the objects on the canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        if (!gameOver) {
            sprite.draw(canvas);
            canvas.drawText("Time Remaining: " + displayTime, 35, 50, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Number of hits: " + hitCount, 250, 50, paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawText("Game Over!", 185, 100, paint);
            canvas.drawText("To go back to the main menu, press the 'back' key", 15, 150, paint);
        }
    }

    //To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            // This just renews the sprite for now
            sprite = new Sprite(this);
            //sound.playZapSound();
            hitCount++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        gameLoopThread.running = false;

        // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                gameLoopThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void getHitCount() {
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }
}
```

**MainMenu class:**

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    private static final int SCORE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;// The request code for the intent

    TextView tvScore;
    String score;
    Intent gameIntent;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_start);
    }

    public void startGame(View v) {
        gameIntent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(gameIntent, SCORE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /* Create Options Menu */
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Respond to item selected on OPTIONS MENU
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //put data in Intent
            case R.id.easy:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Easy chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.medium:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Medium chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.hard:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hard chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.other:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Other chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                    int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                    tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have added 'return hitCount;' to the 'getHitCount' method in the 'GameView' class and this now just crashes the app when I hit the back key.  One the 'MainMenu' class, I have taken out the last line in the 'onActivityResult' method (tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame)); and it no longer crashes but obviously doesn't pass the score across.  I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: what's wrong? There is error in code?

Comment: Try `tvScore.setText(scoreFromGame + "");`

Comment: you are doing ```    returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE", gameView.getHitCount());
``` but you getHiCount return type is void can you explain why

Answer (score 2):

While fetching data from intent you have to use -

```
int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getIntExtra("GAME_SCORE", -1);
// -1 is a default value, use accordingly.
```

Instead of trying to get value from extras.

```
retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
```

Use extras only when you put some value inside bundle.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you've put.  I have the second line you stated in my 'MainMenu' class.  Are you saying I should replace this with the first line?

Comment: Yes in onActivityResult of MainMenu

Comment: When I do that it highlights the "GAME_SCORE" and states that it can't be applied to a string

Comment: Oh I forgot add semicolon at the end. Please insert it.

Comment: I have the semi-colon.  That's not the problem

Comment: Add default value as a second parameter

Comment: Again, not certain what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139377/discussion-between-rasi-and-phil-adams).

Comment: Not possible at the moment.  I'll plod along for now.  Thanks for your efforts

Comment: All sorted now.  I wasn't asking it to find the text box that contains the score (findValueByID), etc.